# Selenium Webdriver error code 502

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver, irb, selenium-webdriver

Somehow from today onward, I am getting following error from my Cucumber code -

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unexpected response, code=502, content-type="text/html"
and then entire HTML text of the Page.

Here is the complete IRB Console Interaction -

```
C:\jruby-1.6.5\bin\jruby.exe --1.8 -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/jruby-1.6.5/bin/jirb - prompt simple
>> require "rubygems"
=> true

?> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true

?> @browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit) 
2.25.2.0
Listening on port 5555
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unexpected response, code=502, content-type="text/html"
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<!-- Page creation information:
   FileName: cannotconnect.html
   Language: [my] New Language Pack
Created with: Language Pack Designer 0.0.0.8
Creation date: 9/26/2011 10:19:48 AM
-->

<!--Head-->
<head>
  <title>Can
```

... and then a big HTML dump that I am not pasting here

& at the end -

```
</html>
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:66:in `create_response'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:59:in `request'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:92:in `create_session'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/ie/bridge.rb:43:in `initialize'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:35:in `for'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:65:in `for'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.5.8/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:35:in `initialize'
from (irb):7:in `evaluate'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1088:in `eval'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:158:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1420:in `loop'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1192:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1192:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/bin/jirb:13:in `(root)'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063:in `load'
from -e:1:in `(root)'>>
```

This started happening suddenly, from this morning, so, my question is .. what does error code = 502 say? If you look at the top of this log - it says

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unexpected response, code=502
```

so, what does it mean? Where is the problem? Is it a proxy issue or something else?
I tried different browsers and have the same issue?

Update -

Here is the funny thing - when I changed my SDK from JRuby 1.5.6 to Ruby 1.87, it works fine... the issue is only with JRuby... Same thing with Ruby SDK works fine... I tried various versions of JRuby.. like 1.6.5 and 1.6.7, and it thrown the same error, but when I try 1.8.7 it works fine - it opens browser with no error –

Here is the code with Ruby 1.8.7

```
C:\Ruby187\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)     C:/Ruby187/bin/irb --prompt simple
>> require "rubygems"
=> true

?> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true

?> @browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x2e18b00 url="http://localhost:5555/" title="WebDriver">

?> @browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x2ef07a0 url="http://localhost:5555/" title="WebDriver">
```

Comment: Here is the funny thing - when I changed my SDK from JRuby 1.5.6 to Ruby 1.87, it works fine... the issue is only with JRuby... Same thing with Ruby SDK works fine... I tried various versions of JRuby.. like 1.6.5 and 1.6.7, and it thrown the same error, but when I try 1.8.7 it works fine - it opens browser with no error

Comment: I got this when my environment had http_proxy/https_proxy set FWIW

Answer (score 3):

502 is the HTTP response code, it means [Bad Gateway](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E502.html) - the problem is due to a misconfiguration or error on one of the upstream servers which your request is travelling through.

Comment: so, my job is to figure out few things - first whether I changed my proxy password.. or is there any proxy setup that has changed. But, here is the funny thing - when I changed my SDK from JRuby 1.56 to Ruby 1.87, it works fine... the issue is only with JRuby... Same thing with Ruby SDK works fine...